# _PHPEnvironmentError, App Engine

Tags: php, python, macos, google-app-engine

I am getting the following error running on a Mac 10.7.5

```
Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
    --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=8080 --admin_port=8888
Python command: /usr/bin/python2.7
INFO     2013-10-17 12:51:15,341 devappserver2.py:661] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2013-10-17 12:51:15,350 api_server.py:332] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-10-17 12:51:15,359 api_server.py:139] Starting API server at: http://localhost:49520
INFO     2013-10-17 12:51:15,366 dispatcher.py:171] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-10-17 12:51:15,375 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8888
ERROR    2013-10-17 12:51:15,722 php_runtime.py:223] The PHP runtime is not available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 219, in new_instance
self._check_environment(php_executable_path)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 171, in _check_environment
version_stdout))
_PHPEnvironmentError: "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php-cgi -v" returned an error [-11]
```

When I click Browse from Google App Engine Launcher (version 1.8.6) I get the following browser error:

```
The PHP interpreter specified with the --php_executable_path flag ("/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php-cgi") is not compatible with the App Engine PHP development environment.
"/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php-cgi -v" returned an error [-11]
```

What I've done so far:

1. reinstalled PHP 5.4
2. upgraded python 2.7.5 (followed these [steps](http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/))

Anyone had same problem and solved it?

Comment: This sounds like https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10135 , which we are working on tracking down.  The commonality so far has been osx 10.7.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that there is a problem with the `php-cgi` binary that comes with the SDK running on your machine. That's a bug that needs to be fixed.

In the meantime though, you can get around the problem by installing `php-cgi` (NB. this is *not* the `php` executable) yourself and invoking it from the development server using the `--php_executable_path` flag.

One way to install the PHP executable is via MacPorts:

```
sudo /opt/local/bin/port install php54-cgi php54-APC php54-calendar \
    php54-exif php54-gd php54-mysql php54-oauth php54-openssl php54-soap \
    php54-xdebug php54-xsl php54-mcrypt
```

After installation, the `php-cgi` (the binary used by the PHP SDK) can be found at `/opt/local/bin/php-cgi54`. You can then use this with the development server using a command like:

```
google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/opt/local/bin/php-cgi54 .
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.5. I installed php-cgi using synaptic and got the same error. So I did small change to the previous answer and it worked for me.

```
google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi helloworld/
```

P.S.

use

```
which php-cgi
```

to locate the cgi executable